# Как отловить что пользователь потянул верхнюю шторку в android?

Tags: android

Как отловить что пользователь потянул верхнюю шторку в android? (где находятся разные настройки)?

Comment: никак, это невозможно.

Comment: Тут уже был такой вопрос. К сожалению, такое отловить нельзя

Comment: и как мне узнать, что пользователь потянул шторку.  Отк или вкл интернет?

Comment: По вопросу определения включения и отключения интернета задавайте другой вопрос.

Comment: Так а чего вы спрашиваете одно, если вам надо совсем другое? Спросите именно то ,что вы хотите, а не то, как вы решили этого достичь. Пользователь может отключить интернет еще тысячей способов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Определить из своего приложения, что пользователь открыл системную "шторку" невозможно.